# Convergence of arc lengths of a sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, uniform-convergence, arc-length

I'm new to this community. I'm trying to solve the following problem. I have a sequence of differentiable functions $f_n: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ which convergences uniformly to a differentiable function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$. In general, this does not imply convergence of the arc lengths 
$L(f_n)= \int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(f_n^\prime(x)\right)^2}\ dx \rightarrow L(f)= \int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(f^\prime(x)\right)^2}\ dx.$
See for example

[Does there exist a if and only if condition so that arc length of a convergent sequence of functions to converge to the arc length of the limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810336/does-there-exist-a-if-and-only-if-condition-so-that-arc-length-of-a-convergent-s)

But my functions $f_n$ and $f$ are all convex. Following the link above, one user said that this would imply convergence of arc lengths.

Does anyone of you know a source in literature or does there exist an elementary proof? I haven't found anything in literature.

Thank you!